# Converting GPS points with timestamp to polylines in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, line, timestamp

I have some GPS coordinates points based on timestamp in a table. My table consists of and id, time_stamp and GPS points as the geometrical data.

I want to create a line by joining all the points from this table. I assume I would have to convert the point table into a polyline table. Should I find out all the points in a particular area using `St_Collect()` function?

I also think that as table has time stamp related to each coordinate, I should follow the timestamp to get the next point in a line?

Putting it in other words, I have created a table with columns as `id(int)` , `time(int)` and `geom(GPS coordinates as POINT)`. I have a set of rows added to this table. Now in order to create a polyline I assume that I should take the time in increasing order and join all the points associated with. Is my view correct?

If yes, I would like to convert these GPS points into a polyline. How should I go about it? Is there any geometric function in PostgreSQL that could support this idea?

Comment: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html does what you want. You certainly do not need to use ST_Collect as the ST_MakeLine essentially takes an array of points, ordered by time, and optionally grouped by track. I think the 2nd example should suit your needs perfectly. If this hasn't answered your question, post your table structure, and I will attempt to write a query for you.

Comment: I see. I get the idea now.

Answer (score 3):

As [commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122065/converting-gps-points-with-timestamp-to-polylines-in-postgresql/311056#comment174198_122065) by John Powell, `ST_MakeLine` in its spatial aggregate form will take rows of points (multipoint or line geometries) and will return a line string (it can also handle arrays of point and multipoint).

Here is an example from `ST_MakeLine` [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) (for PostgreSQL 9+):

```
SELECT gps.gps_track, ST_MakeLine(gps.the_geom ORDER BY gps_time) As newgeom
    FROM gps_points As gps
    GROUP BY gps.gps_track;
```